# Ursina inputfield @ character cannot be typed

Tags: python, input-field, ursina

I tried a 3D project with **ursina engine**.
I put a login part for the first page. Inside it, there is an email field with InputField ursina. But @ character cannot be entered. If anybody has an idea about it? Thanks.

I just put the default value, which is written @, in the input field. But I want the user to enter their email just by typing @ character.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That should be a bug. You can try use another yi library like dear imgui if you wish

Comment: Or just report the bug to pokepetter, the ursina developer

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, but have been fixed now. Update ursina with `pip install https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/archive/master.zip --upgrade` and it should work.

Comment: Hi  @pokepetter, thanks for your effort. I did update. Q and q works well but Alt Gr keys combinations no work. In my keyboard @ { [ # $ all of these characters are pressed with Alt Gr key. And I tried with your inputfield example but all of these characters cannot be typed (I also checked with screen keyboard). If you can fix it I appreciate. Because ursina is very good engine to teach students OOP concepts. So thank you very much.

Comment: I've tested with Alt Gr and it works. Sounds like it didn't actually update. You could try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I uninstalled the ursina package and reinstalled again. It works  @pokepetter as you adviced. I appreciate that.